# How Do I Create A Countdown Time That Resets At A Specific Time

Tags: javascript, datetime, time, timer

Let me first say I do not have a deep understanding of javascript but I know how to work my way around enough to write small scripts for pages.  A client of mine needs me to do the following for a website:

1. Find the user's local time on their computer.
2. Take that local time and subtract it from 6pm.
3. Display that time in a countdown or just a statement letting the user know how much time is left for same day shipping.
4. After 6pm the time resets or disappears until the next business day.

So far I've been able to create the logic for getting the time from the local computer.  I thought I'd be able to use datejs but it does not calculate hours in a day.

Here is the current code I have:

```
var currentTime = new Date()
var hours = currentTime.getHours()
var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes()

var suffix = "AM";
if (hours >= 12) 
{
  suffix = "PM";
  hours = hours - 12;
 }

var suffix = "AM";

if (hours >= 12) 
{
  suffix = "PM"; 
  hours = hours - 12;
}

if (hours == 0) 
{
  hours = 12;
}

if (minutes < 10)
  minutes = "0" + minutes;

document.write("<b>" + hours + ":" + minutes + " " + suffix + "</b>");
```

Comment: Alongside any other testing you are doing, remember to test daylight savings dates, otherwise the `x hours` output might be +/- 1 hour out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if this site would let me comment on other people's answers I'd give the credit for this to Giovanni, but since I can't yet comment on other people's work, here's what needs to change.

```
var currentTime = new Date()
var hours = currentTime.getHours()
var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes()

var suffix = "AM";

if (minutes < 10)
minutes = "0" + minutes

if (hours >= 18)
{
 document.write("You're too late for next day shipping!");
}
else
{
var hoursLeft = 17 - hours;
var minsLeft = 60 - minutes;
if(minsLeft==60){
    minsLeft=0;
    hoursLeft++;
}

document.write("<b> You've got " + hoursLeft  + " and " + minsLeft + " minutes left to qualify for next day shipping! </b>")
}
```

The reason for this is that people who are ordering at 5AM might see think that they have to submit within the next hour for their shipping to be next day when in fact they have the next 13 hours.

**EDIT:** saw your timezone concern and [here](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/convert-the-local-time-to-another-time-zone-with-this-javascript/6016329) is a post that might interest you.

**EDIT 2:** posted the wrong link. The correct one should be up now, though it might be a bit of a dated answer.

Comment: Scott I just tested your code and it worked when I changed my time around.  Again thank you and Giovanni for the help.

Comment: If the currentTime is `new Date(2012, 6, 18, 0, 0, 0, 0)` the output says `You've got 17 and 60 minutes left` instead of 18 hours.

Comment: @andyb Edited to fix that. Thanks.

Comment: Looks like the last edit is off.  My message said 3 hours and 0 minutes were left.  It's off with the last edit.

Comment: @NinaMorena I made a dumb mistake in my if check and only used `=` instead of `==`. It shouldn't give that issue anymore.

Comment: @NinaMorena No problem! By sure to do as andyb said above and check for daylight savings time.

Comment: If `var currentTime = new Date(2012, 2, 25, 0, 0, 0, 0);` which for the UK is a daylight savings day and loses 1 hour, the output should _technically_ be `17 hours 0 minutes` remaining. Although whether users will be more confused with that output is another question! I am not trying to pick apart your answer, I just want to highlight to the OP some of the dangers of date/time calculations.

Comment: nooooo my credittttttt!!! Heh, thanks for fixing up my code. I just fired off an almost there answer without thoroughly testing... Shame on me. Good catch @ScottM

Comment: @GiovanniB I would have just thrown it in a comment on your code since it was mostly your work and I just changed a little bit, but I didn't have enough reputation on the site at the time. The irony is that this post gave me enough rep to do that.

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

```
var currentTime = new Date()
var hours = currentTime.getHours()
var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes()

var suffix = "AM";
if (hours >= 12) {
suffix = "PM";
hours = hours - 12;
  }


if (minutes < 10)
minutes = "0" + minutes

if (suffix == "PM" && hours >= 6)
    {
 document.write("You're too late for next day shipping!");
}
    else
    {
    var hoursLeft = 5 - hours;
var minsLeft = 60 - minutes;
    document.write("<b> You've got " + hoursLeft  + " hours and " + minsLeft + " minutes left to qualify for next day shipping! </b>")
    }
```

Comment: This assumes the customer is in the same time zone, which is not a safe assumption to make. How to deal with timezone offsets in javascript... That i'm not sure.

Comment: @ Giovanni B: You have to get client location(geolocation), then choose correct time zone.

Answer (score 0):

Something similar I solved also yesterday, so this is easy. Here is the javascript code:

```js
function start_onload(last_hour){
    var timeout_message = document.getElementById('timeout_message');
    var currentTime = new Date();
    var hours = currentTime.getHours();
    var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes();
    var seconds = currentTime.getSeconds();
    var expire_time = 0; // in seconds
    if (hours<last_hour) {
        expire_time += (last_hour-hours-1)*3600;
        expire_time += (59-minutes)*60;
        expire_time += (59-seconds);
    }
    else {
        timeout_message.innerHTML = 'It\'s after '+last_hour+' o\'clock!';
        return;
    }
    var expire_time = currentTime.getTime() + 1000*expire_time;
    //console.log(expire_time, hours, minutes, seconds, expire_time);
    function countdown_session_timeout() {
        var current_time = new Date().getTime();
        var remaining = Math.floor((expire_time - current_time)/1000);
        if (remaining>0) {
            hours = Math.floor(remaining/3600);
            minutes = Math.floor((remaining - hours*3600)/60);
            seconds = remaining%60;
            timeout_message.innerHTML = 'Countdown will stop in '+ hours + ' hours ' + minutes + ' min. ' + seconds + ' sec.';
            setTimeout(countdown_session_timeout, 1000);
        } else {
            timeout_message.innerHTML = 'Time is up!';
        }
    }
    countdown_session_timeout();
}
```

Full script @ [pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/3kSGd0Mt) is here.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple countdown timer starting at 30 seconds from when the function is run and ending at 0. After reaching 0 it automatically reset the counter. It goes again to 30 second and this process is continued in a loop

> ```
>   window.onload = function() {    startCountDown(30,
> 1000, myFunction); }
>
>
> function startCountDown(i, p, f) {    var pause = p;    var fn = f;   
> var countDownObj = document.getElementById("countDown");
>
>    countDownObj.count = function(i) {
>       //write out count
>       countDownObj.innerHTML = i;
>       if (i == 0) {
>       //execute function
>       //fn();
>                 startCountDown(30, 1000, myFunction);       //stop
>       return;    }    setTimeout(function() {
>       // repeat
>       countDownObj.count(i - 1);
>       },
>       pause  
>       );    }    //set it going    countDownObj.count(i); }
>
> function myFunction(){};
>
>     </script>
> ```